# How to get css handle for text inside element without elements child

Tags: java, jquery, html, coffeescript

If we use `tbody tr th`, it gives text 'Display model Sample Heading', including its child element (div) text.
Is any possible trick to get only 'Display model' not its child element 'Sample Heading' text?

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th>
      Display model
      <div class="title">Sample Heading</div>
     </th>
    <td class="model">Data</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do let me know if you are expecting some thing else

Comment: It worked but I tried it like $("tbody tr th").contents().not($("tbody tr th").children()).text()

Comment: Please check my demo in the answer below

Comment: Yes it is working, thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo jQuery Way**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('th').css('color','red').children().css('color','initial')

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th>
      Display model
      <div class="title">Sample Heading</div>
     </th>
    <td class="model">Data</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**Working Demo CSS way**

```css
th{
  color:red;
}
th div{
  color:initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th>
      Display model
      <div class="title">Sample Heading</div>
     </th>
    <td class="model">Data</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```